# Rails Console not writing data to database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working through the Hartl tutorial and I have run into a problem.  When I attempt to add a user in the console it doesn't return that it has saved any of the information I just entered. The code is below, hopefully you guys can steer me in the right direction.
The User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessor :name, :email 

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase}
    validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50}
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255},
                        format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                        uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

the error:

```
2.2.0 :003 > User.create(name: "Jim Bob", email: "jim@bob.com", password: "jimmybob", password_confirmation: "jimmybob")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('jim@bob.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["password_digest", "$2a$10$I61hwA3iAQmzsT/wbb0wpOSannOBNPLtQsBhscjakS5OgCi6zJoMq"], ["created_at", "2015-02-13 23:45:32.636129"], ["updated_at", "2015-02-13 23:45:32.636129"]]
   (137.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<User id: 1, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: "2015-02-13 23:45:32", updated_at: "2015-02-13 23:45:32", password_digest: "$2a$10$I61hwA3iAQmzsT/wbb0wpOSannOBNPLtQsBhscjakS5...">
```

I don't understand why the name and the email will not save. Please any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you have defined  attr_accessor for name and email.

attr_accessor will overwrite the methods generated by active records so its not been saved to database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am pretty new to Ruby and I overlooked such a simple thing. I can stop pulling my hair out now. A million thanks.